# Pass iframe text to laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, iframe

I'm having a problem...
My iframe basically an input box (image below) and I want to get the input from the user to my controller
I'm ok with it passing the html intead of the text, it's what I am expecting, since it is not a normal textbox I can't just pass it to laravel because it runs java code.
Any sugestions?

My page:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="content">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-sm-3">
            <h3>Insert text</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-xl-1">
            <form method="POST" action="{{ route('test.create') }}">
                @csrf
                <iframe src="http://localhost:8080/test" width="560" height="650"></iframe>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success w-100 mb-3">
                    Done
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>

@endsection
```

Image (iframe and button only):
[image: Text]

Comment: I guess you need to get the value of the textbox inside iframe using `javascript`.

Comment: I tried using javascript with an id on the iframe but I get VM404:1 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

var iframe = document.getElementById('iframextext');
var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

Comment: Strange because I used it on jsfiddle and it works fine

Comment: I get the error on console, when i do console.log(iframeDocument);

Answer (score 0):

I made this code and it works fine on my end. Do have a look:

**ex1.html** :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title>Page Title</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="sachin"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**ex.html** :

```
<body>
  <iframe src="ex1.html" id="iframeId" style="height:380px;width:100%"></iframe>
 <script>
  $(function(){
    var iframe = document.getElementById("iframeId");
    $(iframe).on('load',function(){
      var innerDoc = (iframe.contentDocument) 
           ? iframe.contentDocument 
           : iframe.contentWindow.document;
      var input= $(innerDoc).find('#sachin');
      $(input).on('keyup', function(){
          //do anything with the value
          console.log($(this).val());
      });

    });
  });
  </script>
</body>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nope, I still get the same error
xtext:82 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://easy.bimby" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at readIframeAndPost (http://easy.bimby/xtext:82:81)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (http://easy.bimby/xtext:92:2)

Comment: What's this? The server IP cannot be reached

Comment: It is basically localhost:80 it is local, just with the custom address on my hosts file, just laravel things

Comment: basically my website is localhost:80 and my iframe is getting localhost:8080